# I chose the wrong 'close reason' for a question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes

In a scenario (that quite a few time happened to me), after submitting a close vote on a specific reason to a question, I then realize that the close reason I have voted is not correct(or some other reason would be more correct). But after retracting my close vote I cannot cast any other voting on closing the question.

Is there a specific reason about this logic?

Wouldn't be more operator-friendly to be able to cast another close vote on an different reason for the same question?

Comment: Yes - it makes you think twice before getting nervous on your voting buttons all the time.

Comment: yes, but mistakes are in our human nature...

Comment: As long as nothing else changed (question didn't get closed for example) I think a five minute grace period for your close vote would make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're taking the time to close a question you should take the time to evaluate why it should be closed. At almost 7K rep, you should be familiar with the close vote options and mistakes shouldn't be frequent.

Each close option has a description to help you determine the best reason to close a question. You can find some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Take your time when closing, there's no rush.

***Edit***

In my opinion, a question that is receiving down-votes or close votes usually doesn't get addressed by the OP.

*If* by chance the OP is seeing the down-votes come in and they attempt to fix their question so that it meets the community guidelines *BUT* it still ends up being a terrible question, then maybe users should be allowed to retract and recast their close vote. In this case, the original reason why a user chose to close the question could be no longer relevant which doesn't help the user understand why their question was closed even after they tried to fix it.

Thanks *Servy* for the discussion.

Comment: Ok, got it. Can you please remove this answer so I can delete my question? Thanks

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Please don't! Others may have the same question, so leave it here.

Comment: Voting is different on meta - downvotes don´t indicate bad questions (that too, but not necessarily). Usually they mean the voters don´t agree with you (don´t want the suggested feature etc.)

Comment: Sometimes multiple close reasons apply, so you end up just choosing one.  If the post is edited such that that one reason no longer applies, you are no longer able to change your vote to another reason that *does* apply.

Comment: @Servy If the post is edited in such a way that your original close vote reason is now irrelevant then there is another issue going on. A question shouldn't be edited _that_ much. Plus, that's why the re-open option is there. If their question is closed because of the original format and they choose to fix it after the fact then they can try to get it re-opened.

Comment: @SeanWM Yes, posts *should* be edited that much.  The whole *point* of voting to close a question is to encourage the author to edit it such that those problems no longer apply.  If they manage to fix those problems before the post collects 5 close votes, then we don't want the post closed for that reason that no longer applies.  However, if the post still has other problems, then we want the post closed for that other reason, until it can be fixed.

Comment: @Servy True, they should edit the question to fix it. But if they manage to edit the question in a way that it now follows SO guidelines then the close votes stop anyways. It won't be closed. Now if they edit the question and it is _still_ poorly written or bad quality then the close votes will still come in. Even if the close votes might not be for the same reason as they were before the edit, the end goal (to close the question) would still be reached.

Comment: @SeanWM Yes, if the post is edited to the point of being a good question it won't be closed, but it if still has other problems, then it will/should be.  Ideally the original close votes would be retracted, but they should be re-cast to the reason that now applies, else the post will be closed, rightly, but for the wrong reason, since people were unable to change the type of vote cast.  People will see the question closed for a reason that doesn't apply, and vote to reopen it, even though it's still close-worthy for other reasons.  The post author also won't have the better guidance.

Comment: @Servy I get where you're coming from in this specific situation. I edited my post. Thanks.